# Angular 6 HttpErrorResponse on Get with 200 status

Tags: angular6, angular-httpclient

This code is making a call to Jasper server to establish a connection using SAML authentication. When the code is  executed it jumps to handleError routine, although it is 200 but still having a parsing error.

**Here is the console info when the code is executed**

This code is making a call to Jasper server to establish a connection using SAML authentication. When the code is  executed it jumps to handleError routine, although it is 200 but still having a parsing error.

**Here is the console info when the code is executed**

```
<p>
<i>
<code>
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
report
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
report
In Report Component init
In connectToJasperconnected
[object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      error: { },
      headers: { },
      message: "Http failure during parsing for THE URL",
      name: "HttpErrorResponse",
      ok: false,
      status: 200,
      statusText: "OK",
      Symbol(INITIAL_VALUE)_h.bdyrahld8ry: undefined,
      Symbol(rxSubscriber)_g.bdyrahld8ry: undefined,
      Symbol(rxSubscriber)_i.bdyrahld8ry: undefined,
      url: "THE URL"
   }



Server Error Status: 200  <-- coming from the error routine
Error Connecting to Jasper Server: [object Object]    <-- coming from the error routine defined in component

</i>

<b>Component code</b>

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('In Report Component init');
    this.connectToJasper();
  }

  connectToJasper() {
    this.samlConnectionService.
    getSAMLConnection().
    subscribe(
      data => this.connected = true,
      error => console.log('Error Connecting to Jasper Server: ' + error)
    );
    console.log('In connectToJasperconnected');
  }

<b>Service code</b>

jasperSamlURL = 'THE URL';

  getSAMLConnection(): Observable<any>  {
   // return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.jasperSamlURL, { responseType: 'text'})
   // return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.jasperSamlURL, { observe: 'response'})
    return this.httpClient.get(this.jasperSamlURL, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' })
    .pipe(
      tap(response => {
        console.log('Http Response Status: ' + response.status);
        console.log('Http Response text: ' + response.statusText);
        console.log('Http Response Type: ' + response.type);
        console.log('Http Response Body: ' + response.body);
      }),
      map(response => this.HttpResponseCode = response.status),
       catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  public handleError(err) {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      // Server side Error
      this.HttpResponseCode = err.status;
      console.log(err);
      console.log('Server Error Status: ' + err.status);
    } else {
      // Client side error
      this.HttpResponseCode = err.status;
      console.log('Client Error Status: ' + err.status);
    }
    return throwError(err);
  }
</code>
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please actually explain the problem in more detail, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: The code and the error is the most simple and well explanatory as it has very useful information about the error for the readers. Also i have included the code for both component and service to make is meaningful for the audience to understand the challenge i am facing. Thanks